# Vim delete to the end of the current line but keep the character under the cursor

Tags: vim

Is there a way to map a shortcut to delete to the end of the line, but keep the character under the cursor? `D` also deletes the character under the cursor. `C` followed by the character and `<ESC>` requires more strokes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just map `D` to `lD` with

```
nnoremap D lD
```

But since it will only save you one keystroke, I'd recommend just training your fingers to make the edit you're going for.

Comment: Thanks. This will alter the meaning of `D`... I was also wondering if this requirement is common enough that there is a common key binding assigned for it.

Comment: @bruin Yes, it will overwrite `D`. No, there is not a default key binding. Normally, the way to create your own bindings without overriding the defaults is to use `<leader>`, e.g. `nnoremap <leader>D lD`, however, this won't save you any keystrokes for such a short key sequence. This is why I don't typically recommend making mappings for 2-key sequences.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again, DJMcMayhem!